# continuous linear operator on Normed space

Tags: functional-analysis

Is it possible to define continuous  linear  operator  on a given normed space.(other than  scalar multiple of  identity) note given space is general

Comment: Of course, any multiple of the identity will work

Comment: its ok ...but i want two operator which not commute....

Comment: Then you should have said so in your question.

Comment: Why not include the motivation in your question?  In this case, you're asking the question because you "want two operators which do not commute".  In general, it is helpful to include some **context** when asking questions on this site (and in general).

Answer (score 0):

If the normed space is complete (i.e. a Banach space), then the [projections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_(linear_algebra)#Projections_on_normed_vector_spaces) define a (non-commuting) class of commuting operators.  In particular: let $X$ be a Banach space.  If $X = U \oplus V$ where $U,V$ are closed subspaces, then the operator $T_U: X \to X$ defined by $T_U(x) = x$ when $x \in U$ and $T_U(x) = 0$ when $x \in V$ is continuous, as a consequence of the [closed graph theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_graph_theorem).

If you want two operators that don't commute, try this: take any finite dimensional $U \subset X$, and take $A,B:U \to U$ to be any non-commuting operators.  Find a closed $V$ such that $X = U \oplus V$.  Then, define $T_A(x) = Ax$ if $x \in U$ and $T_A(x) = 0$ if $x \in V$.  Similarly, define $T_B$.  Then $T_A,T_B$ do not commute.

Answer (score 0):

The Hahn-Banach theorem gives you plenty of finite rank operators and (by taking limits) also compact operators to which you can still add multiples of the identity. A spectacular theorem Argyros and Haydon says that there are Banach spaces on which every continuous operator is a multiple of the identity plus a compact operators.